# Why netstat -o option does not list the chrome tab pid but only its parent browser pid?

Tags: c++, google-chrome, network-programming, pid, netstat

Can somebody tell me why netstat -o is listing down only the one browser pid for all the network connections happening inside chrome...what I mean is even if I have 2 or more tabs opened up in chrome and each tab is sending packets , netstat command
netstat -o-b is showing the following.

PROTO  LOCAL ADDRESS FOREIGN ADDRESS    STATE      PID

TCP     a.a.a.a       b.b.b.b         ESTABLISHED  2240  [chrome.exe]

TCP     a.a.a.a       c.c.c.c         ESTABLISHED  2240  [chrome.exe]

2240 is the chrome browser pid.
But the two connections are established
by 2 chrome tabs having distinct pid's of
there own,but are not being listed. Please shed some light.

And more importantly how to get the pid's of each chrome tab programatically?
Note: I am using windows c++.

Answer (score 0):

PID is a **Process ID** (read: identifier of a running program), not a "Tab ID". The fact that your browser uses tabs is completely irrelevant - your browser (a single program = single PID) may establish many connections. The HTML downloadded by those connections is presented to you in different tabs - that's all. BTW the connections may be terminated after the whole content has been downloaded, but the tab(s) may be still kept open (untill you close them manually). Whether the connections are kept open or not depends on many different factors: the content of the page (if it uses any AJAX, etc.), browser settings.

Comment: If you look in  chrome task manager each tabs will have their own  process Id. "browser (a single program = single PID) may establish many connections. The HTML downloadded by those connections is presented to you in different tabs" but if that be

Comment: Maybe Chrome has its own "task" manager and each task has its own ID (which means it is internal chrome "task id" - not a "process id"), but you gave an output from `netstat` - which does not know anything about them - it knows only about processes present in the system and TCP connections established by them. Chrome tabs are completely irrelevant to `netstat`.

Comment: ok 2 simple doubts if those are tab Id and not Pid 's then why chrome task manager shows those number in the Process Id column?
on top of that if I execute a taskkill command as 
taskkill /F /PID xxxx   where the xxx is the tabId the tab shoots out the following -
" He's Dead Jim
Either chrome ran out of memory or the process for the webpage was terminated for some other reason. To continue reload or go to some other page." and the Process Id inevitably vanishes from the chrome task manager.So I thought that each tab is a spawned process you see.

Comment: Also in the Windows Task Manager it is displayed as PID.